# Mostrar datos de una tabla que contiene 4 llaves foranes

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Estoy Realizando un Procedimiento Almacenado en Mysql.
Requiero mostrar todos los datos de una tabla, esta contiene 4 llaves foranes.
Sucede que al yo querer mostrar mis datos no me muestra los registro.

Realice el mismo proceso con otra tabla que contiene 2 llaves foranes y esta si se efectuó con éxito y me muestra el resulta esperado.

Estaré declarando mal mi Procedimiento?

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_LISTAR_CERDO_REPRODUCIDOS`()
BEGIN
DECLARE CANTIDAD INT;
SET @CANTIDAD:=0;

SELECT
    @CANTIDAD:= @CANTIDAD + 1 AS posicion, 
    cerdos_reproducidos.cerp_id, 
    cerdos_reproducidos.cerp_fecharegistro, 
    cerdos_reproducidos.cerp_tatuaje, 
    cerdos_reproducidos.reproh_id, 
    reproductoresh.reproh_tatuaje, 
    cerdos_reproducidos.reprom_id, 
    reproductoresm.reprom_tatuaje, 
    cerdos_reproducidos.cerp_fechanacimiento, 
    cerdos_reproducidos.cerp_sexo, 
    cerdos_reproducidos.cerp_pesopromedio, 
    cerdos_reproducidos.cerp_pesoreal, 
    cerdos_reproducidos.eta_id, 
    etapa.eta_nombre, 
    cerdos_reproducidos.cerp_fechafinaletapa, 
    cerdos_reproducidos.mov_id, 
    tipo_movimiento.mov_nombre
FROM
    cerdos_reproducidos
    INNER JOIN
    reproductoresh
    ON 
        cerdos_reproducidos.reproh_id = reproductoresh.reproh_id
    INNER JOIN
    reproductoresm
    ON 
        cerdos_reproducidos.reprom_id = reproductoresm.reprom_id
    INNER JOIN
    etapa
    ON 
        cerdos_reproducidos.eta_id = etapa.eta_id AND
        reproductoresh.eta_id = etapa.eta_id AND
        reproductoresm.eta_id = etapa.eta_id
    INNER JOIN
    tipo_movimiento
    ON 
        cerdos_reproducidos.mov_id = tipo_movimiento.mov_id AND
        reproductoresh.mov_id = tipo_movimiento.mov_id AND
        reproductoresm.mov_id = tipo_movimiento.mov_id;
    
    
    END
```

Muchas Gracias de antemano[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: habria que ver los datos... pero todas esas claves suenan muy raras... y ver las relaciones....

Comment: ¿Esa consulta arroja resultados si la ejecutas directamente, **fuera de la SP**?

Comment: no arroja ningún resultado, pero si por ejemplo evito incluir las ultimas 2 llaves foraneas eta_id y mov_id, funciona correctamente. o si quito las 2 primeras reproh_id y reprom_id, dejando solo  eta_id y mov_id tambien funciona correctamente. el problema entra al querer incluir las 4 al mismo tiempo